# How to configure Grunt serve/livereload to combine mustache templates

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mustache, livereload

I'm using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) template to develop a static web site. `grunt serve` nicely works with the [auto reload](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86242-how-do-i-install-and-use-the-browser-extensions-) plugin.

For repeating elements I started to use [{{mustache}}](https://mustache.github.io/) partials and it works like a blast. Now I want the auto reload to assemble my page, so I can look at the resulting page when editing one of the mustache files (either a main file or a partial).

I found a grunt [task for](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-mustache-render) it, but stitching it together eludes me. My config looks like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dev: {
      src: ['src/sass/*.sass'],
      dest: 'dest/css/index.css',
    },
  },
  watch: {
    sass: {
      // We watch and compile sass files as normal but don't live     reload here
      files: ['src/sass/*.sass'],
      tasks: ['sass']
    },
    mustache: {
    files: '**/*.mustache',
    tasks: ['mustache_render'],
    options: {
      interrupt: true
        },
    },  
    livereload: {
      options: { livereload: true },
      files: ['dest/**/*']
    }
  },
  mustache_render: {
    options: {
      {data: 'common-data.json'}
    },
    your_target: {
      files: [
        {expand: true,
        template: '**/*.mustache',
        dest: 'dest/'}
       ]
    }
  }
});
```

I must be missing something since the html files are not updated when I save the file.

Comment: Why dont you add `livereload: true` directly to your mustache watch target options?

Comment: Ahhh didn't know you can do that. Add the recommendation as answer so I can accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `livereload` option directly to your mustache target options.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    mustache: {
    files: '**/*.mustache',
    tasks: ['mustache_render'],
    options: {
      interrupt: true,
      livereload: true
      },
    }
  },
  mustache_render: {
    options: {
      {data: 'common-data.json'}
    },
    main: {
      files: [
        {expand: true,
        template: '**/*.mustache',
        dest: 'dest/'}
       ]
    }
  }
});
```

Also, if you're using `grunt-contrib-connect` to serve your files, don't forget to add the `livereload` option to it:

```
connect: {
    http: {
      options: {
        hostname: "*",
        port: process.env.PORT || 80,
        livereload: true
      }
    }
  }
```